# Custom code containers for google cloud-ml for inference

Tags: google-cloud-platform, google-cloud-ml, gcp-ai-platform-notebook

I am aware that it is possible to deploy custom containers for training jobs on google cloud and I have been able to get the same running using command.

```
gcloud ai-platform jobs submit training infer name --region some_region --master-image-uri=path/to/docker/image --config config.yaml
```

The training job was completed successfully and the model was successfully obtained, Now I want to use this model for inference, but the issue is a part of my code has system level dependencies, so I have to make some modification into the architecture in order to get it running all the time. This was the reason to have a custom container for the training job in the first place.

The documentation is only available for the training part and the inference part, (if possible) with custom containers has not been explored to the best of my knowledge.

The training part documentation is available [on this link](https://cloud.google.com/ml-engine/docs/custom-containers-training)

My question is, is it possible to deploy custom containers for inference purposes on google cloud-ml?

Comment: Try posting the same to all of the following mentioned in https://cloud.google.com/community/ too

1. GCP Sales https://cloud.google.com/contact/
2. The relevant Google group community https://cloud.google.com/support/docs/groups
3. The relevant Slack channel in https://googlecloud-community.slack.com/join/shared_invite/enQtNzM1NDk1MzU2NjQwLTA2MTFkMTAxZjk3N2Q1MmExMTExZTk5MDI4NTM4Y2UzYWI5YjQyOTQyYzUzZDdlYTQ0YzQ5N2M3Y2VkZDg4NDI

Comment: Inference with custom containers is not available as of now. Can you share what system dependencies you need?

Comment: @user260826 there are a significant number of them, one of the many is the use of protocol buffers, with each rerun there may be requirements to compile the code as well, all the other ones we have figured ways to circumvent.

Comment: Probably I am late here but anyone who is looking for this at this time, here is the link to the custom container for prediction/inference [documentation](https://cloud.google.com/ai-platform/prediction/docs/use-custom-container).

Comment: @DipikaBaad Nice thanks for the inputs at the time it was not supported, this will be helpful :)

You can post this as an answer so it reaches more people

Comment: Does anyone have any sample Github project link?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This response refers to using Vertex AI Prediction, the newest platform for ML on GCP.

Suppose you wrote the model artifacts out to cloud storage from your training job.

The next step is to create the custom container and push to a registry, by following something like what is described here:

https://cloud.google.com/vertex-ai/docs/predictions/custom-container-requirements

This section describes how you pass the model artifact directory to the custom container to be used for interence:

https://cloud.google.com/vertex-ai/docs/predictions/custom-container-requirements#artifacts

You will also need to create an endpoint in order to deploy the model:

https://cloud.google.com/vertex-ai/docs/predictions/deploy-model-api#aiplatform_deploy_model_custom_trained_model_sample-gcloud

Finally, you would use `gcloud ai endpoints deploy-model ...` to deploy the model to the endpoint:

https://cloud.google.com/sdk/gcloud/reference/ai/endpoints/deploy-model